# how to check if the number is in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to make a computer vs. computer guessing game and I don't want the computer1 to guess the same number twice. I want to know how to stop this. I believe it is around the if statement, but I'm stuck. I need help.

```
from random import randint

try:
    guess = randint(0,5)
    computer1 = randint(0,5)
    GuessList = [ ]
    GuessList.append(computer1)

    while computer1 != guess:
        print("COmputer guessed ",computer1)
        if computer1 in GuessList:
            computer1 = randint(0, 5)
        #computer1 = randint(0,5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("goodbye")


print("COMPUTER FINALLY GUESSED "), guess)
```

My output is the computer1 guessing the same number more than once, but it will eventually get it.

Comment: "I Need help in my Python code" is *not an appropriate title*. Please fix it to describe the problem you are having. No need to mention Python, either, that is what tags are for.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code *and* accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, show the output you got and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add,

```
while computer1 in GuessList:
    computer1 = randint(0, 5)
```

After your computer1 = randint(0, 5). You might have to remove your GuessList = [ ] because that will reset your GuessList each time. Instead, you should have that at the very start of your code and leave the append statement.

Or you can use

```
computer1 = random.choice(GuessesLeft)
```

GuessesLeft is a list of all the numbers computer1 has not guessed. Each time it makes a guess youc an just delete that item from the list.